# Input type number is returning the value as string

Tags: javascript, html

Why is input type number returning the addition value as string but multiplication value in correct way? Any logic behind this, plz enlighten me

Comment: Please, Gaito, share some code.

Comment: Please share some code to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

`<input>` tags always have a string value. That's just how it works. If you force the input to be a number field, then you will get a string of digits.

Why? Because this is what the HTML spec states will be the case. The the best answer I can give you.

---

> I got the value from text box and multiplied it and it did it on correct way but when adding numbers like 55+10 it returns 5510 –

This is due to type coercion. This means that sometimes a string is converted to a number for you.

```
"55" + 10 // 5510
```

This happens because the `+` operator appends one string onto another.

```
"a" + "b" // "ab"
```

But when you multiply

```
"55" * 10 // 550
```

A string times a string doesn't make any sense, so it assumes you meant to do math and converts it to numbers for you.

---

When you want to do math from input fields you should convert it to a number first to ensure it does the right thing.

```
parseFloat("55") + 10 // 65
```

Comment: I got the value from text box and multiplied it and it did it on correct way but when adding numbers like 55+10 it returns 5510

Comment: you can use parseInt

Comment: See my updated answer